# Main content going underneath the sidebar on lower screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

the goal is to have a 250px col-2 sidebar with a col-10 main body that collapses to a top navbar and main content underneath that

the problem is that the main content body go underneath the sidebar when the screen size changes

how do i fix this?

using bootstrap v5.3.0-alpha1 and react

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export function Holders() {
    const [isSidebarCollapsed, setIsSidebarCollapsed] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleResize = () => {
            setIsSidebarCollapsed(window.innerWidth < 1026);
        };

        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        handleResize();
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
                {isSidebarCollapsed ? (
                    <>
                        <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
                            <span className="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Collapsed Sidebar</span>
                        </nav>
                        <div className="col-12">
                            main content w top navbar here
                        </div>
                    </>
                ) : (
                    <>
                        <div className="col-md-2" style={{ width: 250, height: '100vh', backgroundColor: 'yellow', overflowY: 'auto' }}>
                            sidebar content here
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-10">
                            <h1>Main Content</h1>
                            main content w sidebar here
                        </div>
                    </>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the width and height from your online styles also, You should make a codepen reproducing the error.

Comment: How the result should be? sidebar and main content should stay aside in collapsed view?

Comment: @Wayne removing the 250px width and 100vh from the sidebar doesn't alter the main content body - meaning it doesn't go underneath the sidebar. the problem is that i would like the sidebar to be 250px wide and 100vh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `else` condition. There you set the columns, but the parent does not specify if it is `flex`. You can solve it by adding the `d-flex` into that `div`.

```
<div className="d-flex">
            <div
              className="col-md-2"
              style={{
                width: 250,
                height: "100vh",
                backgroundColor: "yellow",
                overflow: "hidden",
                overflowY: "auto"
              }}
            >
              sidebar content here
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-10">
              <h1>Main Content</h1>
              main content w sidebar here
            </div>
          </div>
```

```js
// Get a hook function
const {
  useState, useEffect
} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [isSidebarCollapsed, setIsSidebarCollapsed] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setIsSidebarCollapsed(window.innerWidth < 1026);
    };

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    handleResize();
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="row">
        {isSidebarCollapsed ? (
          <div className="p-0 m-0">
            <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
              <span className="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Collapsed Sidebar</span>
            </nav>
            <div className="col-12">main content w top navbar here</div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="d-flex p-0 m-0">
            <div
              className="col-md-2"
              style={{
                width: 250,
                height: "100vh",
                backgroundColor: "yellow",
                overflow: "hidden",
                overflowY: "auto"
              }}
            >
              sidebar content here
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-10">
              <h1>Main Content</h1>
              main content w sidebar here
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root")
).render( <
  App / >
);
```

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: seems like it causes more problems - the sidebar has a gap on the left side and it overflows on the x-axis

Comment: It's because of default padding/margin of the elements. You need to set the padding/margin to 0

Comment: Please check the updated snippet. Should be fine now?

Comment: still has an x-axis scroll i think

Comment: Just add  `className="d-flex p-0 m-0 overflow-hidden"`